# AutoLayout dynamic spacing?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, autolayout, psd

I'm pretty new to the whole autolayout design and I'm trying to figure out the best way to make this design compatible on all sizes. I can't seem to find a way to space out each element so the size of each element changes according to the screen size. I know that I can constrain the subviews to the margin but Xcode seems to require a set width and height so the larger screen version ends up looking extremely compressed. (see below) What would be the best way to handle a custom form like this? Basically I need a way to dynamically space out each element.

Each element is on its own. IE text,dividers,icons

[image: autolyout]

Comment: "Xcode seems to require a set width and height" No, it doesn't. Pin the subview's sides to the sides of the superview, and it will adopt the width of the superview. Learn about autolayout!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correctly then I think!you need to set leading,top,tailing and bottom space and aspect ratio if necessary for change in height of textfield to the view of which you need to increase or decrease size according to its width.

[image]